# Multiple TCP streams interfere with each other

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

I have a client that connects to an NFS server and writes data. It is a multiprocess application that creates as many TCP connections as there are processes.  The problem is that if I try one process, the socket blocks on write very little (that is poll() does not pause).  If I increase the number of processes to 8 or more, I find myself being blocked by poll() on each socket about 30% of the time.  Isn't the purpose of using multiple TCP streams having independent send/receive buffers and so they should not block like this?  Why is having multiple streams interfering with each other?  The link is far from saturation (as tested with iperf).

My thoughts on this are that the NFS server will create a socket per TCP connection, and they will have their own receive buffers.  I know I'm making separate TCP sockets for each process, so they should have their own send buffers.  If I'm not saturating the link, why are the sockets blocking?

Comment: Do you have pollout set?  http://linux.die.net/man/2/poll

Comment: Yeah, I'm calling poll with pollout set to see if poll() will block, record the result, and then call poll with an actual timeout value. Doing this gives me poll blocking 30% of the time, and performance is not what I would expect.

Comment: Couldn't it be, that the NFS server is just to lame to serve all your app's requests?

Comment: Are all of the sockets connecting to the same NFS server?  If so, perhaps it is the NFS server that isn't keeping up with the multiple streams of incoming TCP data.  If the server isn't reading fast enough to keep up, the TCP protocol will tell your sending processes to slow down.

Comment: Note that if the NFS server is writing to a spinning-hard disk (i.e. not an SSD) then writing to multiple files simultaneously may be causing the hard disk's heads to seek back and forth a lot, and that can be a real performance-killer.

Comment: It is writing indeed writing to a non SSD disk.  Is there anyway I can verify that it is the server that is slow?  It is an older Linux box that I have root access to, but the NFS server itself is a black box to me.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner - that would be my guess as well.  The NFS server is getting clogged up and the blockage is propagating back to the client/s via. the usual TCP window flow-control.

Comment: @wlformyd If you can temporarily reconfigure your NFS server (or clients) to write the files to a RAM disk (e.g. /tmp maybe?) instead of a real disk, and you find that writing files to the RAM disk reduces or removes the TCP slowdown, that would be a pretty good clue that the hard drive is the bottleneck.

Comment: I think tcpdump could help you to figure out where is the exact bottleneck. You want to improve the performance by increasing the number of processes and thus the number of sockets, but what if the bottleneck is at somewhere else?

Answer (score 2):

You're assuming that the network has infinite bandwidth, and that the server has infinite capacity to service the requests you're sending. It doesn't, in either case. Increasing the number of TCP connections linearly doesn't increase performance linearly. There is only one network; only one server; it only has so many CPUs; and it only has so many disks.  Sooner or later the network will fill, or the server will bog down, which will get reflected back to you as a write stall.